# Running custom Chrome Developer Tools frontend on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, web-inspector

I've downloaded `chrome-linux.zip` from [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html), played with devtools source code (`chrome-linux/resources/inspector`) and tested my modified version with 
`google-chrome --debug-devtools-frontend="/some/path/to/inspector/"`. After that I've decided to run it on Windows, but I can't figure out how to do it. Running chrome with `--debug-devtools-frontend="E:\Users\xxx\Desktop\inspector\"` doesn't seem to work (Chrome runs normally with no changes). I figured out that I should probably download `chrome-win32.zip` and apply my changes on this version of inspector, however there is no `chrome-win32/resources/inspector` folder, only `resources.pak` that I don't know how to deal with. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you run Chrome Canary?

Comment: Yepp: `"E:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --debug-devtools-frontend="E:\Users\xxx\Desktop\inspector\"`

Comment: The switch seems to be removed: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/?date=2012-09-26#debug-devtools-frontend